# ORA-00972 identifier is too long but it isnt

Tags: oracle

i want to insert Data in my Oracle Database. My Tables are already successfully created.
When i now want to do this:

```
INSERT INTO FITNESS_EXERCISE (NAME, DESCRIPTION, E_SETS, REPS, WEIGHT, DURATION) VALUES ("Curl KH", "Curl mit der Kurzhantel für den Bizeps", "3", "8 - 12", NULL, NULL);
```

I get this Error:

```
ORA-00972 identifier is too long
```

But actually it isnt oO

If i count it is a 16 character identifier not a 30 character identifier.

What is going on here?

Comment: Show the table DDL please -- if I had to guess I'd say you have a multibyte character issue here.

Comment: What is the table DDL?

Comment: The "create table" script for it. ("data definition language".)

Comment: CREATE TABLE FITNESS_EXERCISE (
ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL,
E_SETS VARCHAR2(200),
REPS VARCHAR2(200),
WEIGHT VARCHAR2(200),
DURATION VARCHAR2(200))

Comment: `"Curl mit der Kurzhantel für den Bizeps"` has 38 characters. That's greater than 30.

Comment: Hö? But that is defined as VARCHAR2(1000)

Comment: If you use double quotes you are telling Oracle it is an identifier (column name, table name, sequence name...). If it isn't, why use double quotes?

Comment: @user1882812 :`INSERT INTO FITNESS_EXERCISE (ID,NAME, DESCRIPTION, E_SETS, REPS, WEIGHT, DURATION) 
VALUES (1,'Curl KH', 'Curl mit der Kurzhantel für den Bizeps', '3', '8 - 12', NULL, NULL);` ,its because of double quotes

Comment: Oh right -.- double quotes... omg.. how emberassing